# BufferedReader readLine() - Exit when a specific string is entered

Tags: java, bufferedreader

As title, I want it to exit the loop when I entered a specific keyword.

```
try {
    buf = br.readLine();
    while (buf != "doh") {
        buf = br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Two questions:

1. When I enter `doh` from my command prompt, it doesn't exit the loop.
2. If I put `"buf != null"` it works only if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.  If I enter nothing (just press enter key) it doesn't exit the loop.

Comment: The second point is because pressing just enter gives you "\n", but since readLine method deletes the "\n" at the end you just get "" (an empty string), which is different form null. For the first one, just check the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
buf != "doh"
```

to:

```
!buf.equals("doh")
```

And read: [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372).

Answer (score 2):

Use `equals` method instead of `!=`. Operator `!=` will return true only if references to object will not be identical. Method `equal` wil compare strings char by char.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't compare strings (and objects in general) with `==`, that is utilized only for primitives (`int`, `char`, `boolean` etc.). For objects, you use the `equals` method.

```
try {
    buf = br.readLine();
    while (! buf.equals("doh")) {
        buf = br.readLine();
    }
}
```